# How can I clear ram after each for loops?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, spyder, ram

The following code is the piece of code for create noisy audio signal from clean signal but when I ran it , my memory was filling and Spyder freezed. The whole of my audio data file is 2G. How can I clean my memory across the running code or the end of for loop?

```
for i in range(len(path_wav)):
    clean_file.append(path_wav[i])
    clean_wav.append(wave.open(clean_file[i], "r"))
    clean_amp.append(cal_amp(clean_wav[i]))
    clean_rms.append(cal_rms(clean_amp[i]))
    divided_noise_amp.append(np.resize(noise_amp,len(clean_amp[i])))
    noise_rms.append(cal_rms(divided_noise_amp[i]))
    adjusted_noise_rms.append(cal_adjusted_rms(clean_rms[i], snr))
    adjusted_noise_amp.append(divided_noise_amp[i] * (adjusted_noise_rms[i] / noise_rms[i]))
    mixed_amp.append((clean_amp[i] + adjusted_noise_amp[i]))
    save_waveform(path_wav_out[i] , clean_wav[i].getparams(), mixed_amp[i])
```

Also,I break for loop to multi small loops but after running the first loop and memory isn't empty for another loops.

```
for i in range(0,int(len(path_wav)/10)):
    clean_file.append(path_wav[i])
    clean_wav.append(wave.open(clean_file[i], "r"))
    clean_amp.append(cal_amp(clean_wav[i]))
    clean_rms.append(cal_rms(clean_amp[i]))
    divided_noise_amp.append(np.resize(noise_amp,len(clean_amp[i])))
    noise_rms.append(cal_rms(divided_noise_amp[i]))
    adjusted_noise_rms.append(cal_adjusted_rms(clean_rms[i], snr))
    adjusted_noise_amp.append(divided_noise_amp[i] * (adjusted_noise_rms[i] / noise_rms[i]))
    mixed_amp.append((clean_amp[i] + adjusted_noise_amp[i]))
    save_waveform(path_wav_out[i] , clean_wav[i].getparams(), mixed_amp[i])
for i in range(int(len(path_wav)/10),int(2*len(path_wav)/10)):
    clean_file.append(path_wav[i])
    clean_wav.append(wave.open(clean_file[i], "r"))
    clean_amp.append(cal_amp(clean_wav[i]))
    clean_rms.append(cal_rms(clean_amp[i]))
    divided_noise_amp.append(np.resize(noise_amp,len(clean_amp[i])))
    noise_rms.append(cal_rms(divided_noise_amp[i]))
    adjusted_noise_rms.append(cal_adjusted_rms(clean_rms[i], snr))
    adjusted_noise_amp.append(divided_noise_amp[i] * (adjusted_noise_rms[i] / noise_rms[i]))
    mixed_amp.append((clean_amp[i] + adjusted_noise_amp[i]))
    save_waveform(path_wav_out[i] , clean_wav[i].getparams(), mixed_amp[i])
```

Comment: All the audio signals are stored in the RAM as they are stored in list. As signals are also stored in disk. You need not append them to lists.

Answer (score 7):

You cant explicitly free memory, but you can ensure you wont keep references to objects. Python is garbage collected, so you can call garbage collector at the end of the loop, to avoid memory fragmentation, which will improve your performance a bit.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

But you seem to be running out of memory during the loop - what you can do is to reorganize your code - split your it into smaller chunks and execute/gc one by one, so you wont have huge objects in your memory at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to found a solution that the whole of data is used